# Failed: Timed out waiting for Protractor to synchronize with the page

Tags: angularjs, jasmine, protractor, angularjs-e2e, e2e-testing

I faced with very strange problem. During first test run I am almost always receive such error:

> Failed: Timed out waiting for Protractor to synchronize with the page after 50 seconds. Please see https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/docs/faq.md

It does not depend somehow on the test content and after couple of executions everything starting working just fine.

My spec:
Protractor 2.1.0 + Jasmine

It is only occurs for one of my projects, for others everything just fine.

browser.ignoreSynchronization=true; wont work in my case, because it is 100% angular app.

Any ideas on the reasons? It is really strange because it occurs mostly on the 1st run.

I also increased allScriptsTimeout: 50000, but looks like it does not help and it is not a solution

I use

> rootElement: 'html'

param in my config as long as app is defined on html tag

Comment: Can you show where is `ng-app` defined? Thanks.

Comment: it is defined on html tag, I use rootElement: 'html' param in my config.

Comment: But, what is happening in the browser. Do you see your application under test and the correct angular page you are expecting?

Comment: For about first 10 seconds my first page could not be opened and I am on 'data:text/html,<html></html>' - as I know it is ok, but it is quite long for the 1st time. Futher I have loading bar on the page (to show that it is completely loaded, and for some reason it takes quite long to load it. After that on the 2 or 3 or 4 page I have such error, it goes slow, but perform right actions. Manually it is all good, but in the 1st test run I have such error, even if I switch from chrome to firefox for example. On the second run after fail it works very fast as usual.

Comment: Thank you for the information! How do you run your tests and what is inside onPrepare?

Comment: Honestly it was empty and I have not used onPrepare for this project. I tried to add what was recommended here as an answer but no luck (

Answer (score 0):

You can try: `browser.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(2000);` inside `onPrepare()`

I use it for my hybrid app, maybe your angular part of DOM is taking some time to load, and it might help you.

EDIT: F*** comments edits :)

I guess you could hack around it with beforeEach() function, or use it in first test if that happens only then, that would have something like this:

```
dvr = browser.driver; 
browser.ignoreSynchronization = true;
dvr.wait(function() { 
    return browser.driver.isElementPresent(by.css('.ngscope')); }, 30000); //or any other angular element detection
browser.ignoreSynchronization = false;
```

Also I remember that sometimes webdriver lose focus of browser window on start (I haven't seen it in protractor, but it happened to me before with different frameworks), and changing resolution of browser helped `browser.manage().window().setSize(1280, 1024);` )

Comment: it have not helped so far ( I have 100% angular app

Comment: @SergeyTeplyakov I have edited answer, as I have no idea how formatting in comments works :)

Answer (score 0):

I also faced the same issue but after increasing the time out it worked for me

allScriptsTimeout: 72000, and try to add the below lines

jasmineNodeOpts: {
    isVerbose: true,
    includeStackTrace: true,
    showColors: true, 
    defaultTimeoutInterval: 72000
  }